# Exam Class points that don't belong to any question

Tags: numbering, exam

I'm creating a test, and I would like to award some points for respecting instructions, like this

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{sandbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\setcounter{question}{0}

\qformat{}  
\question
Points will be given for
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Quality of drawings
    \part[4] Clear explanation
\end{parts}
\noqformat{}

\question[5]
Draw a ring.
% \setcounter{question}{8}
\question[5]
Add two and two.

\end{questions}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{document}
```

But the setcounter seems to have no effect.

Comment: Thanks, I think I did that, in my last post.

Answer (score 2):

I guess (because I don't totally understand), that you want the two last questions to be numbered 1. and 2. In this case, you set the counter to the wrong value (as it has value 0 at this point by default). If you change it to `\setcounter{question}{-1}` you'll get the correct numbers. To suppress the false entry in the `\gradetable` I use `\item` instead of `\question`. It does produce the correct output (as far as I can see), but I don't know which other things might be implied here.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{sandbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}


\setcounter{question}{-1}

\qformat{}  
\item
Points will be given for
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Quality of drawings
    \part[4] Clear explanation
\end{parts}
\noqformat{}

\question[5]
Draw a ring.
% \setcounter{question}{8}
\question[5]
Add two and two.

\end{questions}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that gives what I want for the question numbers. Unfortunately the gradetable doesn't work.

Comment: @Rob625 see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, you have helped me to achieve what I wanted:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{sandbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\setcounter{question}{-1}

\qformat{}  
\item
Points will be given for
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Quality of drawings
    \part[2] Clear explanation
\end{parts}
\noqformat{}

\question[10]
Draw a ring.
\question[20]
Add two and two.

\qformat{}  
\titledquestion{aesthetic quality} [3]
\noqformat{}    

\end{questions}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well I never knew what exactly you wanted to achieve... Glad I was of help anyway.